# secure sftp password in java program

Tags: java, ftp, passwords, sftp, password-protection

I am writing a Java Program and I have a pretty basic question.

I want to access and write files from/to a Server using SFTP for example with JSch http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ or edtftpj http://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpj/

My question is: With all these tools I have to save the password in the source code. If I want to give this program to anyone and they reverse engineer it they have access to the Server....not desired.

Any ideas how this can be handled?

Answer (score 1):

Either read the password from a file in plain text (which should have its permissions limited so no one but the user can read it) or use a private key for authentication which would be functionally equivalent.

The most secure option would be to not save passwords at all and always ask for user input. With that choice you could optionally save the password in memory for later use but it would be cleared again when you close the program.

Comment: Thanks fsmv! how would you configure a file that can only be read by a certain user?

Comment: On mac or linux you can do `chmod 600 passwordfile` but on windows I think you have to actually go through the GUI right clicking the file and selecting properties then you would go through and make sure no one has read access but the user. Even without the permissions (which a user can set themselves) its probably better to do a file than just put the password in code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively pass in the password as a parameter at runtime

as for configuring a file that can only be read by a certain user, it depends on the OS, but on most linux variants it would look like:

```
chmod 400 file
chown user file
```